# "Default OS account failed" error message when trying to launch a web browser using selenium-python. How do I solve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run the below code to open an instance of edge browser using selenium library in python.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get("www.google.com")
```

When I run the above lines of code, I am getting the below error.

```
[22236:11028:0915/144220.323:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(163)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[22236:11028:0915/144220.354:ERROR:assistance_home_client.cc(32)] File path C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9636_820110299\Default

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62802/devtools/browser/d2966b60-622d-4dc7-915c-da69583c64bd
[22236:11028:0915/144220.594:ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(487)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python\Selenium Projects\Demo.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver.get("www.google.com")
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 353, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute       
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=116.0.1938.81)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7CD943D92+61490]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF7CD8D5FE2+740626]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD6AB6E0]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD694CA0]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD69287C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD693553]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD6AD869]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD72DAB1]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD71390A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD6E7021]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD72CE21]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD7136E3]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD6E5EAA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD6E518B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD6E6634]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF7CDB08D49+1207369]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CD765304]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF7CD8290E1+32273]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF7CD8219D9+1801]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF7CDB07924+1202212]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF7CD8DE978+19784]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF7CD8DAE34+4612]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF7CD8DAF66+4918]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF7CD8CF431+713057]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF6F20257D+29]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF7032AA68+40]
```

I did check the python version and it is "4.12.0". Please help me out solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect - `driver.get("www.google.com")`

Change it to:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

If you notice you were missing `https://` that was the issue. The `.get` method expects a fully qualified URL

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be mixing up raw selenium with frameworks that allow truncated URLs without the protocol, such as [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase):

```
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="edge")
driver.open("www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

That is valid, as the driver has the new `open()` method, which is similar to `get()`, but is less restrictive.

But if you are using raw selenium `get()`, use the full URL with the protocol: `https://www.google.com`.